Strip a line from a variable using awk or sed
There is a Zsh variable with contents like
$if(description-meta)$
  <meta name="description" content="$description-meta$" />
$endif$
  <title>$if(title-prefix)$$title-prefix$ – $endif$$pagetitle$</title>
  <style>
    $styles.html()$
  </style>
$for(css)$
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="$css$" />
$endfor$

I need to remove the <title> line, that is,
  <title>$if(title-prefix)$$title-prefix$ – $endif$$pagetitle$</title>

and to overwrite the variable or create a new one, so that it will be
$if(description-meta)$
  <meta name="description" content="$description-meta$" />
$endif$
  <style>
    $styles.html()$
  </style>
$for(css)$
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="$css$" />
$endfor$

How is it possible using awk or sed?

var=$(grep -v '<title>' <<< $var)

Would remove the lines that contain <title> from the contents of $var (beware it also removes trailing newline characters if any).
Or you could use the ksh-style ${var//pattern[/replacement]} operator as:
set -o extendedglob
var=${var//[^$'\n']#<title>[^$'\n']#($'\n'|)}

To remove all occurrences of <title> along with all the non-newline characters that precede or follow it and one optional newline to the same effect and without having to shove the data through a grep command running in a separate process (and avoiding the newline-stripping issue).
See also:
var=${(F)"${(f@)var}":#*<title>*}

Where

"${(f@)var}" splits $var on line-feeds (using @ inside quotes to preserve empty elements), f being short for ps[\n].
${(F)array:#*<title>*} removes the resulting elements that contain <title> and joins them back with line-Feeds, F being short for pj[\n].


@jsx97, my bad. That statement was incorrect, I've removed it.

I take it that command <<< $var is one of those rare cases where quoting isn't needed?

@terdon, that's zsh, not bash, no split+glob on unquoted variables there. The <<< operator is from zsh. bash copied it a few years later but until relatively recently, in bash, you had to quote that $var there even though that's not a list context! bash would split it on IFS and then join back the result with spaces to make up the contents of the here document!

Stéphane, could you explain what is a practical difference here (or maybe under different circumstances) between var=$(grep -v '<title>' <<< $var) and var=${(F)"${(f@)var}":#*<title>*}?

@jsx97 same as for the other one. It's using zsh operators without having to run a separate  process running a grep executable and is not affected by $(...) stripping trailing newline characters.
